# Dynamic header content in Angular Material Table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im trying to add a dynamic header to my angular material table, but I cant figure out how to do it. I want the month to be in the header in this case.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="month">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{element.month}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.hours}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

I also tried *matHeaderCellDef="let element" but its not working. I keep getting the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined

Any ideas?

Comment: The only solution I can provide – you can re-build table each time you need to change header title( just reassign dataSource object

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: no sorry, I had to go with a different solution and not use Material Table

Answer (score 4):

You can't define variable like `*matHeaderCellDef="let element"` because the header text must not be `undefined` when the table is initialised.

You need to ensure the table is not initialised until you get the month value.

e.g. use `*ngIf="data"` so that the table is not initialised until table source has values.

Assuming month value is loaded through HTTP and stored in `retrievedMonth`,

You can populate the header dynamically like so:

`<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{retrievedMonth}} </th>`

If the month value is in an array or in the same data source as the table, you need to put some filtering logic to extract the month value.